# paper-header-panel inside iron-pages shows no content

Tags: polymer

I am building an SPA polymer 1.0 app that looks like this:

```
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-page"
            selected="{{page}}">
  <div data-page="home">
    <paper-header-panel mode="{{mainMode}}">
      <profile-toolbar></profile-toolbar>
      <div class="content">
        <search-menu></search-menu>
      </div>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </div>
  <div data-page="search">
    <paper-drawer-panel ...>
      ...
    </paper-drawer-panel>
  </div>
</iron-pages>
```

`<profile-toolbar>` is a custom element that contains a `<paper-toolbar>`. If I leave out the `<paper-header-panel>` it works, but there's a padding and the scrolling doesn't work right. So I added a `<paper-header-panel>`.

The second page also contains a `<paper-header-panel>` inside the drawer and works correctly, but I can't make the first page display anything if it contains a `<paper-header-panel>`. What am I missing?

Comment: I also ran into this issue when trying to add routing to [this layout](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout-templates/blob/master/nav-list-detail/src/x-app.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following css class to divs that are direct parents of your paper-header-panels:

```
.content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31510980/1640892) you might try.

[Note this open bug](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/issues/7) that has (apparently) been resolved for all except iOS (Safari).

Comment: The issue is to do with page.js routing being incompatible with paper-header-panel