# How do I animate my <paper-dialog modal> within a <header-panel> in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: animation, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

## Question

> **How do I animate my `<paper-dialog modal>` element inside a `<header-panel>` element given [this bug report](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/issues/7)?**

---

**Background:**

1. `<paper-dialog modal>` elements within a `<header-panel>` appear behind their modal backdrop unless you implement a workaround (i.e., "hack"). [See this bug report](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/issues/7) for more information.
2. I implemented a certain "hack-fix" (workaround) to solve the problem. See my answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394305/polymer-1-0-modal-appears-behind-its-backdrop) for details. Also included below.
3. Apparently, my hack-fix is breaking the animation.

---

**Example of Desired Behavior:**

[See this JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/fogoqupuha/edit?html,output) for an example of the animation behavior I seek. *(Attention Safari users: Use Chrome instead)*

---

**Hack-Fix:**

Firstly, add this function to custom element:

```
// https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/issues/7
patchOverlay: function (e) {
  if (e.target.withBackdrop) {
    e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(e.target._backdrop, e.target);
  }
},
```

Then add `on-iron-overlay-opened="patchOverlay"` to `<paper-dialog>` as follows:

```
<paper-dialog on-iron-overlay-opened="patchOverlay">
```